# Правильный подбор инструментария

Tags: php, java, python, .net

Здравствуйте!

Есть ли смысл использовать например java для веб приложений если ты и так хорош например в таких php фреймворках как codeigniter или же laravel?

А если конкретней инструментарий состоит из .net(c#), java, php, python. Имеет ли смысл использовать только java или .net для веб приложений потому что они предназначены для мидл или лардж приложений? Можно с таким же успехом работать на джанго или ларавел.

Имеем веб приложение которое использует java микросервисы как модель + php как контроллер и google charts как view. Стоит вопрос переделать все приложение в play framework + какой нибудь модуль для чартинга например d3.js. В данный момент все работает идеально jersey работает как микросевис + codeigniter работает как контроллер а google charts как view.

Может все оставить так как есть потому что каждый инструмент используется в своей нише? Буду рад любым советам!

Comment: Здесь такие вопросы не обсуждаются, так как зависят от мнения и не имеют объективно верного решения. Вы вольны использовать те инструменты, которые считаете более предпочтительными для себя, если они не создают каких-либо очевидных проблем (скорость, безопасность и тд)

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за отклик!а вы  пишете фулстэк на java?Или используете в своей нише?Как вы думаете в данный момент ниша java где?

Comment: я android-разработчик. насчет ниш java никаких размышлений не проводил :)

Comment: @pavlofff вы уже нашли его:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо оценивать адекватно реальности:

1. что больше подходит для решения данной задачи;
2. справитесь ли с текущими ресурсами на данных технологиях;
3. что будет в будущем при разрастании продукта, проекта; не будет ли слишком болезненным адаптация позже.

> Есть ли смысл использовать например java для веб приложений если ты и
>   так хорош например в таких php фреймворках как codeigniter или же
>   laravel?

Само собой идеальные знания будут упираться в возможности языка, фреймворка. Если текущих знаний codeigniter и laravel хватает для решения задач, почему бы и не остаться на них.

> Имеет ли смысл использовать только java или .net для веб приложений

Нет, вы вольны комбинировать. Например java отлично подойдет для API сервиса, работы с данными, что-то другое для отображения view.

> В данный момент все работает идеально

Если так, то не стоит задумываться о переходе на что-то другое. Идеально работает и все устраивает - не ищите приключений для вашего продукта.

> Может все оставить так как есть потому что каждый инструмент используется в своей нише?

Если каждый инструмент используется там где он должен использоваться - продолжайте их использовать по назначению :)

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ!Я так понял вы также как и я  пологаете что  ниша java это веб сервисы и API?

Comment: @Tesla считаю, что java хорошо подходит для сервисов и API. Java также подходит для многих других задач. И для сервисов и API также может подойти много других языков, технологий.

Comment: надеюсь "Java также подходит для многих других задач" не относится веб приложения с простым интерфейсом авторизацией и т д :)